# Huge difference between SVD solution output of commons math3 and ojalgo libraries

Tags: java, apache-commons-math, ojalgo

Solution of SVD difference is very high between commons-math3 and ojalgo libraries. Is there any way to reduce the difference based on any input params.

```
        double[][] olsColumns = { { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 },
                { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 }, { 1.0, 1.0 } };
        double[] observationVector = { 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
                0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 };

//Ojalgo
final PrimitiveDenseStore tmpOriginal = PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.rows(olsColumns);
        SingularValue<Double> tmpSVD = SingularValue.make(tmpOriginal);
        tmpSVD.decompose(tmpOriginal);
        double[] singularValues = tmpSVD.getSingularValues().toRawCopy1D();
        double[][] V = tmpSVD.getQ2().toRawCopy2D();
        System.out.println("V" + Arrays.deepToString(V));
        System.out.println("Singular values" + Arrays.toString(singularValues));
        try {

            // MatrixStore<Double> doubleMat = tmpSVD.solve(tmpOriginal,
            // PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.column(Utils.prepareObservationVector()));
            MatrixStore<Double> solution = tmpSVD.getSolution(PrimitiveDenseStore.FACTORY.column(observationVector),
                    tmpSVD.preallocate(tmpOriginal));
            System.out.println("Solution " + Arrays.toString(solution.toRawCopy1D()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//Commons-Math3

        RealMatrix newPredM = new Array2DRowRealMatrix(olsColumns);
        SingularValueDecomposition svd = new SingularValueDecomposition(newPredM);
        // RealMatrix covariance = svd.getCovariance(0);
        // System.out.println("covariance"+Arrays.deepToString(covariance.getData()));
        System.out.println("V" + Arrays.deepToString(svd.getV().getData()));
        System.out.println("Singular values" + Arrays.toString(svd.getSingularValues()));
        double[] solution = svd.getSolver().solve(new ArrayRealVector(observationVector)).toArray();
        System.out.println("Solution" + Arrays.toString(solution));
```

Commons Math3 Solution: `[0.01612903225806451, 0.016129032258064502]`

OjAlgo Solution Solution: `[7.614155324982286E13, -7.614155324982295E13]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of ojAlgo are you using?

When I try that code I get an exception because the "preallocated" matrix you supply to the tmpSVD.getSolution(...) method is the wrong size/shape. If you simply remove that second argument the allocation is done for you and the code works. I get this result:

```
V[[0.707106781186548, -0.707106781186547], [0.707106781186547, 0.707106781186548]]
Singular values[13.638181696985853, 9.035878689445474E-15]
Solution [0.016129032258064484, 0.01612903225806446]
```

Comment: the version I have used is
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: ojAlgo
Implementation-Version: 47.1.2

Comment: I get below error when I remove the second argument of tmpSVD.getSolution(...) 
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
 at org.ojalgo.matrix.store.operation.MultiplyBoth.lambda$static$12(MultiplyBoth.java:556)
 at org.ojalgo.matrix.store.PrimitiveDenseStore.fillByMultiplying(PrimitiveDenseStore.java:768)
 at org.ojalgo.matrix.decomposition.RawSingularValue.doGetInverse(RawSingularValue.java:541)
 at org.ojalgo.matrix.decomposition.RawSingularValue.getSolution(RawSingularValue.java:178)
 at org.ojalgo.matrix.decomposition.RawSingularValue.getSolution(RawSingularValue.java:173)

Comment: The latest release is v47.2.0. There has been work on related parts of ojAlgo lately. Maybe this has been fixed then. Try using what's in the development branch: https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/compare/master...develop

Comment: I have tried with v47.2.0 the output is same but I had to remove second argument of tmpSVD.getSolution(...) .
I cloned the dev branch shared and build the artifacts and with those artifacts, I got the same output mentioned in your answer.
I have 2 more questions
1. When will the v47.3.0 available on maven repository, any timeline
2. Is second argument no more needed for getSolution method.

Comment: The second argument is, and always has been, optional. It's there to allow for efficient memory usage.Open an issue at GiHub regarding the bug.